# How to insert excel data into oracle sql using python?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

Hi I'm trying to load data from excel to oracle  SQL table using Python. I'm able to load single record but don't know how to load from excel pandas dataframe. the excel file contains more than 6000records. Please find my below code. Kindly help to alter the code.

```
import cx_oracle 
import pandas as pd

try:    
   con = cx_oracle.connect(connection detials) except 
KeyError:   
   cx_oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=path)

df=pd.read_excel(Path)
df.head()

cur = con.cursor() sqlTXT="TRUNCATE TABLE smax_eu_load.HIST_USER_UAT" 
cur.execute(sqlTXT)

sql="INSERT INTO HIST_USER_UAT(ID, FULLNAME, SSO) VALUES('aa','bb','cc')" 
cur.execute(sql) 
con.commit() 
cur.close() 
con.closse()
```

Comment: have you tried df.to_sql()? something like, df.to_sql('HIST_USER_UAT', conn, if_exists='replace')

Comment: Hi Lei Yang, Sorry I'm not following, do you mean using for loop function for rows and columns?

Comment: Hi Sreeram, no i didnt know it can be done, i thought it is for mysql could you please share a reference

Comment: Pandas has I/O capability with various storage system. In your case, reading [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) as a start.